# why can't Gatsby command work even if I have installed it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

[image: terminal outputs]
[image: 2]

I have followed a tutorial to create a folder that holds all npm globally installed, but I still can't run gatsby command even if I have installed gatsby-cli. What is wrong?

Comment: It would be better for your to share what error you got. Command not found like things?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your environment does not recognize `gatsby` command.

Try this:

```
npm install -g gatsby-cli
```

If the error persists, try to close and reopen the shell, sometimes it caches the previous state.

You can check for further details [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-zero/).

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried several times to reopen it and reinstall it, but the command still couldn't be recognized. just added a new screenshot, if you would like to check to the problem.